# How to fix "Reduce unused JavaScript" and "Minify JavaScript"

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, performance

I have a Joomla website that I wish to make faster by following the indications given by the GoogleSpeed Insight page:

- "Reduce unused JavaScript" and
- "Minify JavaScript"

[google insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Feasy-moving.ca%2F&tab=mobile)

The goal is to solve the problem.

I couldn't find where it is:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js
Google Insight should solve it first but I cant.

My site [get in web site](https://easy-moving.ca)

by the way, I see this: [image: get in to see image]

[image: should google]

Comment: Thank you for joining and posting Boris.  Since you are new, please take our [tour].  Also, your question states your requirements, but does not include any evidence of attempts to self-solve. Can you please [edit] your post to include your efforts and any relevant web resources that you encountered before asking your question? By showing what you've tried, you prevent volunteers giving you advice that you already know/tried.

Comment: Let's be careful that this question isn't a moving target.  If you can resolve your problem, please post an educational answer instead of editing the question.  If you have a new issue, please post a new question (the new question may reference this page for context).

Comment: got it. thank you sir I will.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve it. JCH Optimize solved the problem almost.
You can add Js what you want to remove if unused.
you should do:

1. Downloads plugin JCH Optimize. I use free version
2. get in setting plugin
   3.Basic Features ---> Remove Unused Javascript ---> add item
3. save and clear chache
   I was wrong before. It works only if you have script on you server or database. dosent work if looks like https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/731015690569070?v=2.9.42&r=stable